# Node.js formatted console output

Tags: node.js, console

Is there a simple built-in way to output formatted data to console in Node.js?

Indent, align field to left or right, add leading zeros?

Comment: I don't know about any of those, but similar one is `colors` and it can format the strings outputted e.g. `"Green colour".green`

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking to do something like `console.setup({ color: 'green', prepend: '0000' })`, but already built in? You could make your own logging method or override the `stdout.write` method (although people suggest not overriding native functions).

Comment: I was thinking about `printf()` with various handy format modifiers to the output string.

Comment: The answers below are good. In addition though, if you also want to add automatic colors to your standard Node.js output, check out [manakin](https://github.com/vitaly-t/manakin).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Two new(1) built in methods [String.Prototype.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and [String.Prototype.padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) were introduced in ES2017 (ES8) which perform the required padding functions.

(1) *node >= 8.2.1 (or >= 7.5.0 if run with the --harmony flag)*

Examples from the mdn page:

```
'abc'.padStart(10);         // "       abc"
'abc'.padStart(10, "foo");  // "foofoofabc"
'abc'.padStart(6,"123465"); // "123abc"
'abc'.padStart(8, "0");     // "00000abc"
'abc'.padStart(1);          // "abc" 

'abc'.padEnd(10);          // "abc       "
'abc'.padEnd(10, "foo");   // "abcfoofoof"
'abc'.padEnd(6, "123456"); // "abc123"
'abc'.padEnd(1);           // "abc"
```

For indenting a json onto the console try using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). The third parameter provides the indention required.

```
JSON.stringify({ a:1, b:2, c:3 }, null, 4);
// {
//    "a": 1,
//    "b": 2,
//    "c": 3
// }
```

Comment: May be worthwhile to note that this is supported only in node >= 8.2.1 (or >= 7.5.0 if run with the `--harmony` flag) since it is rather recent yet.

Comment: This is working for me on v8.1.2 even without the flag.

Comment: Don't forget to use .toString() if you're not seeing this work.

Answer (score 36):

If the data is tabular, then the simplest way would be to do it with `console.table`

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/console.html#console_console_table_tabulardata_properties

This is the code.

```
console.table(
  COMMANDS.map(command => {
    return {
      "Long Option": command.long_option,
      "Short Option": command.short_option,
      Description: command.description
    };
  })
);
```

You don't need external libraries for it.
Here is sample output. You only need to pass an array object.
[image]

Not only in Nodejs, but it also works in chrome.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table

[image]

Comment: Any way to left indent the contents of column? It defaults to center alignment.

Comment: Is there way to align text to left?

Comment: Now it's aligned to the left. See the change here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/50135

Answer (score 28):

There's nothing built into NodeJS to do this. The "closest" you'd come is `util.format`, which still doesn't do much unfortunately ([reference](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format)).

You'll need to look into other modules to provide a richer formatting experience. For example: [sprintf](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js).

Sprintf-js allows both positional (0, 1, 2) arguments and named arguments.

A few examples of padding and alignment:

```
var sprintf=require("sprintf-js").sprintf;

console.log(sprintf("Space Padded => %10.2f", 123.4567));
console.log(sprintf("    _ Padded => %'_10.2f", 123.4567));
console.log(sprintf("    0 Padded => %010.2f", 123.4567));
console.log(sprintf(" Left align => %-10.2f", 123.4567));
```

Results:

```
Space Padded =>     123.46
    _ Padded => ____123.46
    0 Padded => 0000123.46
 Left align => 123.46
```

Comment: `util.format` is better than nothing. But, not much better. :) If it was just part of `console.log` ... then it would make more sense.

Comment: I added a few examples to round out the answer.

Comment: how do i pass a string?

Comment: @chovy-the docs have a lot of examples and I'd suggest you start there.

Answer (score 7):

If you have simpler needs you can look into [util.format](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format). It can generate string from various parameters. If you want printf like formatting you can use either [sprintf](https://npmjs.org/package/sprintf) package or [sprintf-js](https://npmjs.org/package/sprintf-js) package.

Comment: Seems just like my answer? :)

Comment: Yeah, just few minutes late.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Log4JS](http://stritti.github.io/log4js/docu/users-guide.html#install), which is an attempt at a functional port of Log4j

Answer (score 3):

You might also like string-kit and terminal-kit.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-kit

https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminal-kit

https://blog.soulserv.net/terminal-friendly-application-with-node-js-part-ii-moving-and-editing/

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although the link may contain the answer to the question, make sure you provide the essential information on your answer, so that if that link is ever taken down, the answer is still valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I combine util.format and "".padStart/"".padEnd together,as described in posts above,  then I get what I wated:

```
> console.log(util.format("%s%s","Name:".padEnd(10), "John Wall"))
Name:     John Wall
```

Answer (score 1):

A version of `console.table` for **NodeJS** with align.

> ⚠ This is only for console version! ⚠

```js
/**
 * @param {NonNullable<{
 *    [key: string]: string
 *  }>} data
 */
const consoleTable = (data) => {
  if (typeof data === 'object') {
    const e = Object.entries(data);
    let kl = 0;
    let vl = 0;

    for (const [k, v] of e) {
      if (k.length > kl) {
        kl = k.length;
      }

      const s = JSON.stringify(v);
      const l = s ? s.length : 0;

      if (l > vl) {
        vl = l;
      }
    }

    /** @type {{ [key: string] : string }} */
    const result = {};

    for (const [k, v] of e) {
      const s = JSON.stringify(v);
      result[k.padStart(kl)] = s ? s.padEnd(vl) : v;
    }

    console.table(result);
  } else {
    console.table(data);
  }
};
```

Output example:

```
┌─────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│     (index)     │                                         Values                                         │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│     CONFIG_FILE │ '"/Users/ecuomo/projects/zzzzz/xxxxxxxx/tttttttttt-web/jjjjjjjjjj-commons/config.env"' │
│        NODE_ENV │ '"development"                                                                       ' │
│         APP_ENV │ '"local-dev-edu"                                                                     ' │
│     APP_VERSION │ '"0-local-ecuomo"                                                                    ' │
│        BASE_URL │ '"http://localhost:3000"                                                             ' │
│    CDN_BASE_URL │ '"http://localhost:3000/static"                                                      ' │
│    API_BASE_URL │ '"http://localhost:3000/api"                                                         ' │
│           MONGO │ '"mongodb://mongo:27017/xxxxxxxxxxprod"                                              ' │
│      MYSQL_HOST │ '"mysql"                                                                             ' │
│      MYSQL_PORT │ '3306                                                                                ' │
│    MYSQL_DB_ETL │ '"xxxxxxxxxx_etl"                                                                    ' │
│  MYSQL_DB_STATS │ '"xxxxxxxxxx_stats"                                                                  ' │
│ MYSQL_DB_ZAPIER │ '"xxxxxxxxxx_yyyyyy"                                                                 ' │
│   POSTGRES_HOST │ '"postgres"                                                                          ' │
│   POSTGRES_PORT │ '5432                                                                                ' │
│     POSTGRES_DB │ '"xxxxxxxxxx"                                                                        ' │
│      REDIS_HOST │ '"redis"                                                                             ' │
│      REDIS_PORT │ '"6379"                                                                              ' │
│    REDIS_MASTER │                                       undefined                                        │
│      REDIS_MODE │ '"single"                                                                            ' │
└─────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```