# Why is \t won't print tab in certain cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

In Node.JS I would like to print a line with tabs as a delimiters,

can someone please explain why it is not printing a tab in the first console.log?

here is a code snippet:

```js
var a = "1233423"
console.log(a + '\t' + a);  // shows 1233423 1233423
console.log(a + 's\t' + a); // shows 1233423s 1233423
```

Answer (score 2):

The console has a tabstop at position 9
The added `s` makes the console go over it and moves to the next tabstop

See what happens when I add a digit

```js
var a = "12334230"
console.log(a + '\t' + a);  // shows 12334230 1233423
console.log(a + 's\t' + a); // shows 12334230s 1233423
```

You may want to investigate [Node.js formatted console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837697/node-js-formatted-console-output)

Comment: what does it mean tabstop at position 9? can i somehow put the tabs unrelated to the tabstops? maybe using file stream?